# Saving Embed Code From Dashboard Widget

Tags: dashboard

So I'm trying to make a widget on the dashboard where this church can paste the iframe embed code from Facebook Live and then it puts that on the correct page on the site.

The problem is that I'm using Ajax to save the widget options but when you put HTML into the textarea, it does not save. I dumped the $_POST on ajax call, and the textarea has no data if its HTML code.

```
function add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'stream_options',            // $widget_id 
        'Stream Settings',          // $widget_name 
        'stream_options_widget' // $callback 

    );
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_dashboard_widgets' );

function stream_options_widget() {

    $code = stripslashes( get_option( 'stream_code' ));
    $status = get_option( 'stream_status' );

    $live = $offline = "";

    if($status == "1") {
        $live = "checked";
    } else {
        $offline = "checked";
    }
        echo "
        <form action='". admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ."' method='post'>
        <div class='options_class_wrap'>
            <textarea name='stream_code' id='stream_code' col='10' style='width: 100%' rows='5'>". $code ."</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class='options_class_wrap'>
            <label for='live'><input type='radio' ". $live ." name='stream_status' id='live' value='1' /> Live</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for='offline'><input type='radio' ". $offline ." name='stream_status' id='offline' value='0' /> Offline</label>
        </div>
            <input type='hidden' name='ajax_action' value='stream_options_ajax_call' />
            <input type='hidden' name='_ajax_nonce' value='". wp_create_nonce('stream_options_ajax_call')."' />
        <br />
        <div class='options_buttons'>
            <input type='submit' class='button' value='Save'>
        </div>";
}

function stream_options_ajax_call() {
    if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_ajax_nonce'], 'stream_options_ajax_call' )) {
        die(-1);
    }


    $status = wp_kses($_POST['stream_status'],array() );

    update_option( 'stream_code', stripslashes(wp_filter_post_kses(addslashes($_POST['stream_code']))));
    update_option( 'stream_status', $status );

    wp_redirect('/wp-admin/index.php');

    exit;
}

function stream_options_ajax_call_init() {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['ajax_action']) && $_REQUEST['ajax_action'] === 'stream_options_ajax_call') {
        do_action( 'wp_ajax_stream_options_ajax_call' );
    }
}

if (is_admin()){
    add_action('wp_ajax_stream_options_ajax_call', 'stream_options_ajax_call');
}

add_action( 'init', 'stream_options_ajax_call_init');
```

Comment: You haven't hooked `stream_options_ajax_call()` to the `wp_ajax_` hook in this code. Does that not exist in your full code either? And I don't see any JS for submitting with AJAX.

Comment: Yes it was there. This is a dashboard widget.

Comment: I still don't see an AJAX request.

Comment: From what I got off of a tutorial (which I dont remember now) didnt have javascript in a dashboard widget. I can't just enqueue scripts

Comment: If you're not using JavaScript it's not AJAX (it's the J), but as far as I'm aware scripts enqueued with `admin_enqueue_scripts` will load on the dashboard. But is there a particular reason you're using a Dashboard widget? A customiser field, or even a settings page, would be *much* easier to set up.

Comment: It changes every week. A dashboard widget is easiet for this client to update the code instead of going into a settings page

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the main problem here is ultimately just that `wp_filter_post_kses` is probably filtering out iframes. But I also want to address the round about way you're handling the form. You're not doing AJAX, which is sending the request to the server via Javascript, but you're trying to hook into the AJAX hooks and then run them manually on admin-post.php? It's all a huge mess.

Here's working code that will do what you want with actual AJAX, and I'll go over some things to pay attention to at the bottom:

```
function wpse_211908_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'wpse_211908_stream_options',
        'Stream Settings',
        'wpse_211908_stream_options_widget'
    );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_211908_add_dashboard_widgets' );

function wpse_211908_stream_options_widget() {
    $code = stripcslashes( get_option( 'stream_code' ) );
    $status = get_option( 'stream_status' );
    ?>

    <form id="stream_options" method="post">
        <p><textarea name="stream_code" rows="5" class="widefat"><?php echo esc_textarea( $code ); ?></textarea>

        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="stream_status" value="1" <?php checked( $status, '1' ); ?>> Live</label>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'stream_options_ajax_call' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="wpse_211908_save_stream_options">

        <p><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save">
    </form>

    <script>
        ( function($) {
            var $form = $( '#stream_options' );
            var $button = $form.find( 'input[type="submit"]' );

            $form.on( 'submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $button.prop( 'disabled', true ).attr( 'value', 'Saving...' );

                $.ajax( {
                    url: window.ajaxurl,
                    method: 'post',
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    complete: function() {
                        $button.prop( 'disabled', false );
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        $button.attr( 'value', 'Saved' );
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $button.attr( 'value', 'Save' );
                    },
                } );
            } );

            $form.on( 'input change', function() {
                $button.attr( 'value', 'Save' );
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>

    <?php
}

function wpse_211908_save_stream_options() {
    if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'stream_options_ajax_call' ) ) {
        http_response_code(403);
        exit();
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        http_response_code(403);
        exit();
    }

    update_option( 'stream_code', $_POST['stream_code'] );

    $status = isset( $_POST['stream_status'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_option( 'stream_status', $status );

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_211908_save_stream_options', 'wpse_211908_save_stream_options', 99 );
```

Firstly, notice that I have prefixed all my functions and any variables that are going to be shared with WordPress to avoid conflicts. This is a good practice and I recommend it. Names like `add_dashboard_widgets` are just begging to
cause conflicts.

Notice the `script` tag in the widget. This is the JavaScript that will send the AJAX request. Because I have a hidden field named `action` with the value `wpse_211908_save_stream_options`, this means that it will become `$_POST['action']` and I can handle it by using the `wp_ajax_wpse_211908_save_stream_options` hook. Using Javascript for the submission means that you don't need to have a page load when submitting.

Also in the widget notice that I have used [`esc_textarea()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_textarea/) to make sure HTML in the `$code` variable doesn't break the HTML of the widget. And notice my use of [`checked()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) as a simpler way of outputting the checked attribute.

The second function is what handles the AJAX request. Notice that I can handle everything in the one function rather than adding actions which check fields and trigger actions. In here I send 403 errors if the nonce doesn't verify, or if the user does not have permission to update settings.

One thing you'll notice is that I don't do anything special to `$_POST['stream_code']`. Filtering submitted HTML isn't necessary when we're already checking that it's a trusted user. If you want to lock this down more, you can use `wp_kses`, but you need to provide your own list of allowed elements since iframes will get stripped by `wp_filter_post_kses()`.

Then notice that for the `$_POST['stream_status']` I simply check that it exists (with AJAX it won't come through at all when not checked) and manually set to `'0'` or `'1'`. `wp_kses()` is considerable overkill for sanitizing a checkbox.

Finally, to use the HTML on the front end, just use: